# I want to find if a value on one spreadsheet is also in another spreadsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have one spreadsheet with over 6000 entries - I need to see if any of these entries, based on a value in one specific column, is also contained anywhere in a different spreadsheet that has over 9000 entries.

Answer (score 1):

Use `MATCH` with `range_lookup` (the third parameter, I think) set to `FALSE` so it performs an exact match.

`=MATCH(your_value, [other.xlsx]Sheet1!$A$1:$A$9999, FALSE)`

(untested)